# SCRIPT7002 error on REST calls with Windows 8

Tags: rest, cordova, windows-8

I have an apache cordova application being compiled in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 with Hybrid Tools CTP 2.  It works as expected on all platfroms except for Windows 8.  My REST calls are failing with this error,

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.

How do I enable these requests for Windows 8?  I have fixed a lot of issues by removing remote references to things and including them locally, but obviously I can't do this for API services.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 8 apps (and this is specifically for 8 vs. 8.1) you need to grant both the "Internet (Client and Server)" and "Private Networks" capabilities in the package.windows80.appxmanifest file so that you can make REST calls over the user's public and work/private internet connections:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

There's a complete writeup on these capabilities here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx